# The expected number of steps a bug walks through all edges

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

(It's from one Quant related interview question)

There is a tetrahedron(A, B, C, D) and a bug at one of the vertices(like A) is performing a random walk on the edges (all edges with the same length), at any vertex where it can select any of the 3 edges to walk on with same probability(1/3), What is the expected number of steps it needs till it walks through all different edges(six different edges)?

It's easy to work out the expected number of steps it walks from one to two different edges, E(0->1) = 1, E(1->2) = 3/2, of course, it's easy to call the Markov chains expected time to absorption, but it's complex if you continue to calculate the transition probability recursively.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2719306/edit) your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I agree with Leyla that you should give context, motivation, and show some effort. As a starter, can you solve the simpler problem of the expected time until we walk over 2 distinct edges?

Comment: I agree the expected time to get 2 distinct edges is $1+3/2$.  Then, what about the expected time to get 3 distinct edges? This is now when the picture drawing of "state" (which includes location) may be useful.  An observation is that, by symmetry, once you get 2 distinct edges, you _must_ be in a single particular state (regardless of how you got those first two edges).  However, that state might change to a new state before you get the third edge.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: the analogous problem for vertices can be modelled through a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) on $8$ states, representing the visited vertices. These states can be lumped into $4$ states $L_0,L_1,L_2,L_3$, leading to a random walk on $L_0 L_1 L_2 L_3$ moving toward the right. We go from $L_0$ to $L_1$ with probability $1$, from $L_1$ to $L_2$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$, from $L_2$ to $L_3$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. It follows that the expected number of steps for visiting the whole set of vertices is $1+\frac{3}{2}+3=\frac{11}{2}$.
[image]
Can you do the same (or something similar, based on the sub-problems

```
    /|\       |\       |\     |\     \
   / | \      | \      | \    | \     \
   \ | /    \ | /    \ |      | /     /
    \|/      \|/      \|      |/     /
```

) with the edges?

Comment: @MishaLavrov: indeed this was intended as a hint, it is just a solution (with some details to fill) to the "*dual*" problem, now clarified.

Comment: This is a good solution for the vertex problem but I don't know if it really serves as a good "hint." The vertex problem just so happens to have a simplified state space that depends only on the set of vertices visited, not current location within that set, and we always make "forward progress."  Unless there is some magical simplification that I am missing, the link problem requires a more complex state structure and would use a recursive relationship between expected times to get between states. I think my first comment above may be a more realistic first-step to do, no?

Comment: @Michael: you are correct about the loss of the "*forward progress* property", but on the ther hand the edges problem can be broken into simpler instances <|> , /|>, |>, and we may recover some symmetry by identifying opposite edges. Anyway, let us wait for further improvements of OP's question.

Comment: Location is also important in those simpler instances you draw.  Anyway, I think the sub-problem of computing the expected time to visit 2 distinct edges is a realistic computation to ask someone to do: It makes progress on the larger problem, introduces crucial notions of "state," and, if someone cannot do that sub-problem, there is no hope to understanding the larger problem.